# Wordpress custom endpoint returns Security violated

Tags: rest-api

Good day, im implement the a custom endpoint for my wordpress site, the intialization for my custom endpoint is:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( '/v1', '/b2buser', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'userMigration',
    'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
  ) );
} );
```

When i call the endpoint sending body fields as JSON format, i capture the fields and im using wp_insert_user o wp_create_user but wordpress response me a message "**Security violated**"

```
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login'  =>  $request->get_param( 'USUARIO' ),
        'user_pass'   =>  $request->get_param( 'CLAVE' ),
        'user_email' => $request->get_param( 'CORREO' ),
        'first_name' => $request->get_param( 'NOMBRE_CONTACTO_PRINCIPAL' ),
        'display_name' => $request->get_param( 'NOMBRE_CONTACTO_PRINCIPAL' ),
        'role' => 'cliente_clase_b',
        'locale' => 'es_ES',
        'use_ssl'=> true,
        'show_admin_bar_front' => 'true',
        "meta_input" => $meta
    );


    $user_id = wp_insert_user( wp_slash($userdata )) ;
    
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        $res = new WP_REST_Response(['test'=>'11111']);
        $res->set_status(200);
        
        return ['req' => $user_id];
    }
    
    return new WP_Error( 'error', __( $user_id->get_error_message(), "migration process" ) );
```

[image]

The error is weird, im using a basic auth.

**As additional note:** when is use a GET and exclude the functions wp_create_user or wp_insert_user, wordpres response correctly, please i need a help with this issue, thank you.

Comment: I've had this issue using 'Custom User Registration Fields for WooCommerce' plugin? (I imagine you've sorted it by now though)

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the security checks by inserting the user into database directly.

This is dirty solution but it works always.

```
<?php        
// Create a new user
global $wpdb;

// Generate a random key for the user activation
$activation_key = wp_generate_password(20, false);

// Generate the hashed password
$hashed_password = wp_hash_password($password);

// Insert user data into the users table
$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'users',
    [
        'user_login' => $username,
        'user_pass' => $hashed_password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'user_registered' => current_time('mysql'),
        'user_activation_key' => $activation_key,
        'user_status' => 0,
    ],
    [
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d'
    ]
);

// Get the newly created user ID
$user_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

// Insert user role into usermeta table
$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta',
    [
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'meta_key' => $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities',
        'meta_value' => serialize([$role => true])
    ],
    [
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ]
);

// Optionally, you can add the user to the usermeta table with additional information
$wpdb->insert(
    $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta',
    [
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'meta_key' => 'first_name',
        'meta_value' => 'John'
    ],
    [
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ]
);
```